# Is my Magsafe 2 Power Adapter fake?

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe

Look please at the pictures below. The old charger is genuine when I bought a ME865 (sealed box).
Today I bought MF841 (2nd) along with a new one. Is this a fake?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
AC Charger Information:

  Connected:    Yes
  ID:   0x0921
  Wattage (W):  60
  Family:   0x0085
  Serial Number:    0x0105181c
  Charging: No
```

Comment: The 3rd image (with CE, UL, trash can symobls, etc) is a bit blurry. It will list the manufacturer. Can you upload a better image or tell us what the manufacturer is on both of them?

Comment: @UnassumingGuy Is it more clear now?

Comment: Can you put them on a scale and weigh them?

Comment: They both are made by Delta Electronics (or so they say). From the counterfeit adapters I've seen they are manufactured by another company.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is genuine. I recently purchased an 85W off Amazon that's similar to yours. It came in all the Apple packaging trappings and I think it's genuine because my guess is Apple changed the location of the serial number to that harder-to-print location specifically to make the game harder for fakers. (Why would a faker bother to move the serial number into such an awkward location? It's quite possible that printing in that confined space requires special equipment, which would force fakers to either forego the serial number, use a sticker, or use two pieces of plastic instead of one solid piece.)